# Fixed navbar only on desktops?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best solution to make top navbar fixed only on large displays (desktops/tablets)?

Comment: Use css media queries - [LINK](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: Sorry but I cant post my answer but here is my way to attain what you need using bootstrap 3. `<div class = "navbar nav navbar-fixed-top hidden-xs visible-lg-inline"></div>`. Just use helper classes (`hidden`, `visible`) of bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Just use media queries for applying the rule only in monitors (`only screen`) above a minimum size:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px){
 .navbar{ // navbar class
   position:fixed;
 }
}
```

Comment: This post has been flagged automatically as low-quality because there's no explanation about the code excerpt.